# Everyone in the Gemara can resurrect the dead?

Tags: sources-mekorot, resurrection-of-the-dead

Although I have never seen a source for such a concept, I have heard from a handful of people over the years that every individual mentioned in the Gemara is capable of resurrecting the dead. Is this true? If so, what is the source for such a concept?

Comment: Perhaps Avoda Zara 10b אזל ר' חנינא בר חמא אשכחיה דהוה קטיל אמר היכי אעביד אי איזיל ואימא ליה דקטיל אין משיבין על הקלקלה אשבקיה ואיזיל קא מזלזלינן במלכותא בעא רחמי עליה ואחייה ושדריה אמר ידענא זוטי דאית בכו מחיה מתים מיהו בעידנא דאתינא לא נשכח איניש קמך

Comment: I think I saw this in the Kohelles Yitzchak (https://hebrewbooks.org/34762).

Comment: https://he.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%97%D7%9D_%D7%A9%D7%9C_%D7%97%D7%96%22%D7%9C_%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%97%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%91%D7%93%D7%99%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%9D

Comment: Every individual? There are lots of bad individuals mentioned in the Gemara.

Comment: @Alex That's what I wondered too, but first wanted to see if this was actually a true statement then go from there.

Comment: @Alex I heard it as *every Amora*, not every individual. It makes a lot more sense that way.